# Why wont my console log '0' when I try to click my controls?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to coding and programming and I have been following, on Youtube, a screen recording of a programmer making a responsive thumbnail slider using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I've gotten to a point where I am trying to get "0" to show up in my console when I click the controls for the slider, but I can't get the controls to respond to my cursor. The thing is that it works when I put the code into here but it does not work in any of the browsers on my computer. I tried Google Chrome and Internet Explorer. I even tried updating Notepad++ and Google Chrome but nothing is working.

Can someone tell me why this is happening? My code is below.

```js
const controls = document.querySelector(".artcontrols");
const container = document.querySelector(".thumbnailcontainer");
const allBox = container.children;
const containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
const margin = 30;
var item = 0;
var totalItems = 0;

// item setup per slide

responsive = [{
    breakPoint: {
      width: 0,
      item: 1
    }
  }, //if width greater than 0 (1 will item show)
  {
    breakPoint: {
      width: 600,
      item: 2
    }
  }, //if width greater than 600 (2 will item show)
  {
    breakPoint: {
      width: 1000,
      item: 6
    }
  } //if width greater than 1000 (4 will item show)
]

function load() {
  for (let i = 0; i < responsive.length; i++) {
    if (window.innerWidth > responsive[i].breakPoint.width) {
      items = responsive[i].breakPoint.item
    }
  }
  start();
}

function start() {
  var totalItemsWidth = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < allBox.length; i++) {
    //width and margin setup of items
    allBox[i].style.width = (containerWidth / items) - margin + "px";
    allBox[i].style.margin = (margin / 2) + "px";
    totalItemsWidth += containerWidth / items;
    totalItems++;
  }
  //tumbnail-container width set up
  container.style.width = totalItemsWidth + "px";

  //slides controls number set up
  const allSlides = Math.ceil(totalItems / items);
  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  for (let i = 1; i <= allSlides; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.id = i;
    li.innerHTML = i;
    li.setAttribute("onclick", "controlSlides(this)");
    ul.appendChild(li);
    if (i == 1) {
      li.className = "active";
    }
  }
  controls.appendChild(ul);
}

//when clicked numbers slide to next slide
function controlSlides(ele) {
  //select controls children 'ul' element
  const ul = controls.children;

  //select ul children 'li' elements;
  const li = ul[0].children;

  //find who is now active
  var active;

  for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if (li[i].className == "active") {
      //find who is now active
      active = i;
      console.log(active)
    }
  }
}

window.onload = load();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.thumbnailslider {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.thumbanilslider .thumbnailcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  transition: margin 1s ease;
}

.thumbnailslider .artitem {
  height: 175px;
  background-color: grey;
  line-height: 175px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols ul li {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 33px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols ul li.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
</div>
<div class="thumbnailslider">
  <div class="thumbnailcontainer">
    <div class="artitem">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
      7
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
      8
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
      9
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
      10
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Control Slides -->
  <div class="artcontrols">

  </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Since it works here but not on your machine locally, something is probably wrong in the way you have your files set up. Is JS file in same folder as HTML file, or referenced properly ? Could you try to validate your full html file somehow (sometimes errors in html file prevent some script from loading, but browser will still display what it can) ? I suspect you just show us a part of the file, since there is an invalid closing `</div>` tag at the beginning of the HTML.

Comment: If this codes are working here so your browsers are Okay, place the JavaScript codes under you local and then try

Comment: @Pac0 It is in the same folder and I believe it is referenced properly. Where should I post my full html?

Comment: @AlirezaNazari what do you mean place the JavaScript under my local?

Comment: If the same code is working here and the same code is not working in your local file, maybe JavaScript are loading before HTML tags and its good idea to place all you custom JS code end of you body tag

Comment: @AlirezaNazari that didn't work. Can you think of anything else that it could be?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/1cb5tdzx/

I edited your function .u forget to change active class when clicked.

```js
const controls=document.querySelector(".artcontrols");
 const container=document.querySelector(".thumbnailcontainer");
 const allBox=container.children;
 const containerWidth=container.offsetWidth;
 const margin=30;
 var item=0;
 var totalItems=0;
 
 // item setup per slide
 
 responsive=[
 {breakPoint:{width:0,item:1}}, //if width greater than 0 (1 will item show)
 {breakPoint:{width:600,item:2}}, //if width greater than 600 (2 will item show)
 {breakPoint:{width:1000,item:6}} //if width greater than 1000 (4 will item show)
 ]
 
 function load(){
  for(let i=0; i<responsive.length;i++){
   if(window.innerWidth>responsive[i].breakPoint.width){
    items=responsive[i].breakPoint.item
   }
  }
  start();
 }
 
 function start(){
  var totalItemsWidth=0
  for(let i=0;i<allBox.length;i++){
   //width and margin setup of items
   allBox[i].style.width=(containerWidth/items)-margin + "px";
   allBox[i].style.margin=(margin/2)+ "px";
   totalItemsWidth+=containerWidth/items;
   totalItems++;
  }
  //tumbnail-container width set up
  container.style.width=totalItemsWidth + "px";
  
  //slides controls number set up
   const allSlides=Math.ceil(totalItems/items);
   const ul=document.createElement("ul");
   for(let i=1;i<=allSlides;i++){
     const li=document.createElement("li");
     li.id=i;
     li.innerHTML=i;
     li.setAttribute("onclick","controlSlides(this)");
     ul.appendChild(li);
     if(i==1){
      li.className="active";
     }
         
   }
   controls.appendChild(ul);
 }
 
 //when clicked numbers slide to next slide
 function controlSlides(ele){
  //select controls children 'ul' element
  const ul=controls.children;
  
  //select ul children 'li' elements;
   const li=ul[0].children;
  
  //find who is now active
  var active;
  var paginations=document.querySelectorAll(".artcontrols ul li.active")[0].className="";
    
    document.getElementById(ele.id).className="active";
  for(let i=0;i<li.length;i++){
   if(li[i].className=="active"){
    //find who is now active
    active=i;
        console.log(active);
   }
  }
 }
 
 window.onload=load();
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.thumbnailslider {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.thumbanilslider .thumbnailcontainer {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 transition: margin 1s ease;
}

.thumbnailslider .artitem {
 height: 175px;
 background-color: grey;
 line-height: 175px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #ffffff;
 float: left;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 padding: 15px;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols ul {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols ul li {
 height: 35px;
 width: 35px;
 border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
 margin: 4px;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 33px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols ul li.active{
 background-color: green;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
 <div class="thumbnailslider">
   <div class="thumbnailcontainer">
    <div class="artitem">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    2
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    3
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    4
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    5
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    6
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    7
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    8
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    9
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    10
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <!-- Control Slides -->
   <div class="artcontrols">
    
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this and it didn't work. Is there anything else that you think it could be?

Comment: Did u control jsfiddle l shared ?

Comment: I don't know what that is. I clicked the link but I don't know what I'm supposed to do with it.

Comment: I created snipped is that what u want or not ?